# api connection to back-end data store is failing

Tags: node.js, api

I am getting TypeError: usergrid.client is not a constructor".
Any one has any suggestions? I am trying to connect to a backend data store using nodejs. Any suggestion?

```
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var usergrid = require('usergrid');
    var config = require('./config');

var client = new usergrid.client({
    'orgName': config.organization,
    'appName': config.application,
    'clientId': config.clientId,
    'clientSecret': config.clientSecret,
    'authType': usergrid.AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
    logging: config.logging
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use new with usergrid.client. 
It could be this way depending on usergrid structure.

```
var x=new usergrid() ;
var client=x.client({..});
```

Comment: I used your suggestion and getting "TypeError: usergrid is not a constructor"

Comment: usergrid is a node_modules?